# TFS 2012 does not add TFS server to "Team Foundation Server list"

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

Earlier I was using Azure team foundation server and recently I tried to connect to different team foundation server. But I am not able to switch from Azure team foundation server to other.

When I connect to other TFS server, it does not show me login text boxes to enter my credentials to add that server to *Team Foundation Server list* to connect later. It only shows *Insert a smart card* options.

[image]

Even after I uncheck "Remember my credentials" I am not getting login text boxes to enter my credentials, so I am not able to connect to that server.

I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate version.

After disabling smart card service, there is no option for anything:
[image]

It's very strange and the problem persist even after I reinstalled Visual Studio.

Comment: A workaround. Could you try to temporarily disable the smartcard service using msconfig and then retrying this?

Comment: can you please tell me in detail how to disable smartcard service?

Comment: Ctrl+R -> type msconfig -> Enter -> Click Services tab -> find smart card entry here -> uncheck the checkbox -> apply -> OK

Comment: @allen please check my edited post after disabling smart card service. Its so weired now.

Comment: It looks like that authentication is required. Is this a DoD TFS instance perchance?

Comment: @aclear16 no. its the regular TFS that comes with Visual studio 2012 ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the saved credential from `Credentials Manager`.

- Load `Control Panel`
- Load `User Accounts`
- Click `Manage your Credentials`

Take a look in `Windows Credentials` and delete any saved credentials that are associated to the Azure account.

Comment: Also try going to the TFS web page in Internet Explorer and logging in there. Save your credentials and it *should* flow through.