# How to create a testflight invitation code?

Tags: ios, testflight

I am a registered iOS developer and a developer friend of mine is trying to send me a testflight version. 
For some reason he can't sent me an invitation - I believe this is because I am registered as a developer and used my only apple ID for the dev apple account registration.
Nevertheless, I am currently beta testing another app... So something weird is going on... 
Furthermore, I notice there's a "Redeem" button at the bottom of the testflight app so there should be a place to invite other users using invitation codes.

So how to send a testflight invitation code?
If this is not possible, how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This question is on-topic, as it deals with using an important service within Apple's development ecosystem. For example, compare with this arbitrarily chosen [service-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15014500/145173).

Comment: Consider reopening it. I was searching for the same problem. 70k views seems many are searching the same.

Comment: I just flagged this requesting to move it over to https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DVLaMmGxR8

Answer (score 82):

after you add the user for testing. the user should get an email. open that email by your iOS device, then click "Start testing"  it will bring you to testFlight to download the app directly. If you open that email via computer, and  then click "Start testing" it will show you another page which have the instruction of how to install the app. and that invitation code is on the last line. those All upper case letters is the code.

Comment: This was the correct answer at the time, Apple just recently changed it so this no longer works. Stop down-voting, anything past -1 is enough to notify others that this no longer works, at this point you are just lowering a users reputation for answering the correct answer (at the time), (s)he couldn't have known Apple would change it.

Comment: Check this today using the method above. Clicking the "Start Testing" button in the email on my computer indeed did load a web page in my browser with instructions on downloading the TestFlight app and using the redemption code. Code worked to accept the invite. @AlbertRenshaw

Comment: @TuplingD yes they added the code back a month or two ago I noticed, probably by popular request!

Comment: As of today, my email from TestFlight does not have "start testing" anywhere in it and TestFlight does not show the app as being available for testing.

Comment: As of today... clicking the "View in TestFlight" link in Outlook downloaded an HTML file, which when opened contained instructions and the invitation code.

Comment: For me the solution was to simple, but spent hours until found it, open the email link on a computer or divices without test flight, it will open a web instead of the app, the code will be there! :)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw that does not mean much, answers should be updated by the time they are found. If an answer is upvoted, that may not stay forever. Software and programmers should be up to date.

Comment: @Michael It's important to note that when I made this comment, this answer was at negative 10 or so.

Comment: Thanks Jesuslg123. Nice UI Apple! How on earth does this shit get past QA. Oh well, I guess the two QA's Apple has must be busy.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DVLaMmGxR8

Comment: For a more recent answer that works in Jan 2021 see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155164/568458 then if you open the link in the email in a device that doesn't have testflight installed the link shows a page that shows the code